# how to create a new play project with sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi i am trying to create a play project with sbt (scala build tool) i am follwing [this tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/NewApplication)

under the section "Create a new application without having Play installed"
 I follwed the same instruction

this is my project/Build.scala file

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object  ApplicationBuild extends Build {
    val appName ="playsbtproj"
    val appVersion  ="1.0"
    val main = PlayProject(
    appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang =SCALA
    )
}
```

and this is my project/plugins.sbt file

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.3")
```

when i typed sbt in my projects folers sbt gives me following erorrs

```
[info] Loading project definition from /opt/programs/play/playsbtproj/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /opt/programs/play/playsbtproj/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[error] /opt/programs/play/playsbtproj/project/Build.scala:3: not found: object PlayProject
[error] import PlayProject._
[error]        ^
[error] /opt/programs/play/playsbtproj/project/Build.scala:8: not found: value PlayProject
[error]     val main = PlayProject(
[error]                ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? sarawaheed@ubuntu:/opt/programs/play/playsbtproj$
```

please help me how to correct this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[valid documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/NewApplication)** for selected version (2.2.3 in your case).

Works out-of-the-box